# Retrieve value of nested tag and store it in nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I’m trying to store values from between XML tags into a list and it’s not working. I’m having trouble wrapping my head around this. The following code gives
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'`

Here is the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse(‘//storage1//harison/dev/gis/cocalig.xml’)
    root = tree.getroot()
input['merchandise_db'] = {'host': root.findall('cali_merchandise_db_ref').find('host').text, 'db_name': root.findall('cali_merchandise_db_ref').cali_merchandise_db_ref.find('db_name').text, 'schema': root.findall('cali_merchandise_db_ref').cali_merchandise_db_ref.find('schema').text, 'user': root.findall('cali_merchandise_db_ref').cali_merchandise_db_ref.find('user').text, 'pwd': root.findall('cali_merchandise_db_ref').cali_merchandise_db_ref.find('password').text}

input['incident_db'] = {'host': root.findall('incident_db_ref').incident_db_ref.find('host').text, 'db_name': root.findall('incident_db_ref').incident_db_ref.find('db_name').text, 'schema': root.findall('incident_db_ref').incident_db_ref.find('schema').text, 'user': root.findall('incident_db_ref').incident_db_ref.find('user').text, 'pwd': root.findall('incident_db_ref').incident_db_ref.find('password').text}

input['projection_db'] = {'host': root.findall('cali_projection_db_ref').incident_db_ref.find('host').text, 'db_name': root.findall('cali_projection_db_ref').incident_db_ref.find('db_name').text, 'schema': root.findall('cali_projection_db_ref').incident_db_ref.find('schema').text, 'user': root.findall('cali_projection_db_ref').incident_db_ref.find('user').text, 'pwd': root.findall('cali_projection_db_ref').incident_db_ref.find('password').text}
```

I understand why the code gives the error but not sure how to fix it. Before when I just outputted the value to the screen I iterated using `#for cali_merchandise_db_ref in root.findall('cali_merchandise_db_ref'): and`cali_merchandise_db_ref.find(‘xyz’).text`

**TL;DR**
Given the xml file

```
<animal>
 <lastmodified_date>4/6/2015</lastmodified_date>
 <data>some junk goes here</data>
 <dog>
   <sound>woof</sound>
   <hastail>yes</hastail>
 </dog>
 <cat>
   <sound>meow</sound>
   <hastail>yes</hastail>
 </cat>
</animal>
```

How do you get

```
input['dog']['sound'] = 'woof'
input['cat']['sound'] = 'meow'
input['dog']['hastail'] = 'yes'
input['cat']['hastail'] = 'yes'
```

**Failed attempt #2:**

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> with open ("cocalig.xml", "r") as myfile:
...     data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
...
>>> root = ET.fromstring(data)
>>> mydic = {}
>>> for element in root:
...     host_tag = element.find("host")
...     mydic[element.tag] = {"host": host_tag.text}
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
>>>
```

Comment: don't use builtin names (`input`) for variable names

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to fit your adjusted example**

Your example can be solved like this:

```
root = ET.fromstring("<animal> <lastmodified_date>4/6/2015</lastmodified_date><data>some junk goes here</data><dog><sound>woof</sound><hastail>yes</hastail></dog><cat><sound>meow</sound><hastail>yes</hastail></cat></animal>")

mydic = {}
for element in root:
    if element.tag in ('lastmodified_date', 'data'):
        mydic[element.tag] = element.text
    else:  # here come the elements describing animals
        mydic[element.tag] = {}
        for animal_element in element:  # "sound" and "hastail" in undefined order
            mydic[element.tag][animal_element.tag] = animal_element.text
```

This generates following dictionary:

```
{'lastmodified_date': '4/6/2015', 'data': 'some junk goes here', 'dog': {'hastail': 'yes', 'sound': 'woof'}, 'cat': {'hastail': 'yes', 'sound': 'meow'}}
```

Basically, you don't need to explicitly say that you want to extract a "sound" and a "hastail" from an animal. You just say: I want all sub-elements of an animal. But if you want to consider missing tags as an error, you'd have to explicitly check for them:

```
else:  # here come the elements describing animals
    mydic[element.tag] = {}
    try:
        sound = element.find("sound")
        mydic[element.tag][sound.tag] = sound.text
    except:
        # do some error handling
```

You can solve your problem in this manner too. Chaining `findAll` and `find` calls might sound intuitive, but findAll just returns a list of found elements on which searching works different. So instead, just iterate over all elements.

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: for `inputValues[element.tag] = {"host": host_tag.text}`

Comment: Oh, this probably means, you searched for the "host" tag on the wrong level of your xml, so that `host_tag` is now None. From your code I can see, that the structure is: root > db refs > rest (host, db name, etc.). You need to ensure, that you search for "host" on the last level. Please show the code of your new approach, so we find the problem. The `For` in your snippet makes no syntactic sense. You need a for loop over the root element like in my answer.

Comment: I posted the attempt to the original question as it was too long for a comment. I also updated the example animal xml as the xml file I am actually using may be structurally more complex. Thanks.

Comment: @Celeritas I updated my answer to fit your case. I hope, it works for you now!

Answer (score 0):

In short you need:

```
tree.findall('dog')[0].findall('sound')[0].text
```

Here is a rundown:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.fromstring(s)
>>> tree.findall('dog')[0].findall('sound')[0].text
'woof'
```